# Will I incur a performance hit by using Class.forName(...) in a High Volume application?

Tags: java

So here is what I am trying to do.  I have a web service that ultimately calls a simple dispatcher.  From the request the dispatcher instantiates a handler for that particular type of request.  All handlers implement the same interface.

The problem I am struggling with is the best way for the dispatcher to instantiate the handler.

The 2 solutions I have are:

1. Use a Map with the key being the scenario (the same as on the request) and the value being the String to look up the class.

   ```
   scenarios = new HashMap<String, String>();
   scenarios.put("A", "com.xyz.handlers.ScenarioAHandler");
   ```

   Then do this:

   ```
   handlerClass = Class.forName(scenarios.get(scenario));
   handler = (HandlerInterface) handlerClass.newInstance();
   ```
2. The other solution I have is to just use the class at the value.

   ```
   scenarios = new HashMap<String, Class>();
   scenarios.put("A", ScenarioAHandler.class);
   ```

   Then I could just do this to get an instance of the handler:

   ```
   handler = (HandlerInterface) this.scenarios.get(scenario).newInstance();
   ```

Are either of these better than the the other or is there an even better solution I have not considered yet?

Comment: Convention over configuration comes to mind - but there is no guarantee that it can work. In stead of doing option 1, you can derive the classname from the scenario like String classname = "com.xyz.handlers.Scenario" + scenario + "Handler". I don't know what naming convention the scenario has, if it can contain conflicting characters this solution is no good. I don't think you will notice any real difference no matter what choice you make, but there is but one way to know for sure: measure it!

Comment: Can you reuse a handler instance?

Comment: May be you should use `Factory Pattern` to create `handlers` for every `request`, and just use `new handlerType` in your `factory class`

Comment: @Jukka The handlers "could" be reused from one call to the next but would not be reused (re instantiated) within a single call to the service.

Comment: If you can reuse instances then just pre-instantiate all the handlers and place them in a Map<String, HandlerInterface>.

Answer (score 2):

The second scenario is a little bit faster since it does not have to go through the "if this class is not loaded then load class" code (see the `forName` method in [Class.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java)). But as Sajan Chandran suggests, a factory will be faster and safer:

```
public class HandlerFactory {

private HandlerFactory() {}

public static HandlerInterface getHandler(String scenario) {

    HandlerInterface handler = null;

    // switch is just as fast as HashMap lookup.
    switch(scenario) {

    case "A": handler = new ScenarioAHandler(); break;
    case "B": handler = new ScenarioBHandler(); break;

    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("No handler defined for scenario " + scenario);

    }
    return handler;
}
}
```

Comment: So I understand the safer part, but what makes this faster?

Comment: `new Object()` is a little bit faster than `Object.class.newInstance()`

Comment: I am having trouble finding the answer myself but does a switch in java test each case from top to bottom?